# How to increase VLC RAM buffer for offline files?

Tags: performance, vlc-media-player, cache

I would like to configure VLC player to preload a significant portion (like a hundred megabytes or so) of a video file from the hard disk to RAM before playing it. Is this possible?

Comment: If computers worked as they ought to, we wouldn't have to do this...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Go to the dropdown `Tools -> Preferences`, then on the preferences menu make sure you have `All` selected on the bottom left corner of the screen.

From there select `Input / Codecs` from the left hand side and scroll all the way down to the bottom on the right hand side to get to the section called `Advanced`.

In there the option for `File Caching` sets how many milliseconds of video to buffer in RAM when the video source is a file.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you! This is right what I need. This has solved my problem with seeing squares when watching videos from a USB drive of mine. I have just put 10000 (10 seconds, as far as I understand) to all the fields and everything works perfect now.

Comment: Do you know what happens when it is set to 0? Does VLC cache as much as it can when the value is 0 or does it default to something else?

Comment: @displayName I don't know what it will do. Go ahead and try and report back your findings.

Comment: I was looking for the value that would maximize the buffering. After I set it to 0, the video didn’t pause ever to buffer but that isn’t a decisive way to say that setting to 0 maximizes the buffer.

Comment: Using 0 seemed to perform the best out of the buffering options for me.